# I am trying to use Amazon Forecast and I am getting this error: input data has invalid timestamp value. Even thought I fixed the time in Excel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timestamp, amazon-forecast

I uploaded my data to S3 bucket and fixed the timestamp in excel to be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and I still get the following error:\nInput data has invalid timestamp value: 3/23/2021 5:00:00, Please ensure timestamp values match the specified format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Could you please help me out! I have been trying different things since yesterday and it seems trivial. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, I went to the Excel file, select the time column, then select the format to be custom. Then I copy-paste the format from Amazon Forecast, which is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. Then saved the file, upload it to S3 bucket then used in Amazon Forecast, and it worked!